# Loading Bitmaps Efficiently - showing solid color on start

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

I have used the [Loading Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) from developer's Guide and followed the instructions point to point from that tutorial.

As you may know, this is the code I used:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth,int reqHeight){
    //Raw height and width of the Image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height>reqHeight || width>reqWidth) {
        final int heightratio = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);

        inSampleSize = heightratio < widthRatio ? heightratio : widthRatio;
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,int reqWidth,int reqHeight){
    //first decode with inJustdecodeBounds = true to check dimensions.

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    //Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    //Decode bitmap with inSampleSize
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

And I am calling this method in a switch case as:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            learn_full_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            learn_full_iv.startAnimation(anim);

            switch (id) {
            case R.id.a:
                //learn_full_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.aeroplane);
                learn_full_iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.aeroplane, learn_full_iv.getWidth(), learn_full_iv.getWidth()));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Width : " + learn_full_iv.getWidth() + "Height : " + learn_full_iv.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                playSound(1, 2);
                break;
            case R.id.b:
                //learn_full_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);
                learn_full_iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.ball, learn_full_iv.getWidth(), learn_full_iv.getWidth()));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Width : " + learn_full_iv.getWidth() + "Height : " + learn_full_iv.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                playSound(3, 4);
                break;
            case R.id.c:
                //learn_full_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.camel);
                learn_full_iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.camel, learn_full_iv.getWidth(), learn_full_iv.getWidth()));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Width : " + learn_full_iv.getWidth() + "Height : " + learn_full_iv.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                playSound(5, 6);
                break;
            case R.id.d:
                //learn_full_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.drum);
                learn_full_iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.drum, learn_full_iv.getWidth(), learn_full_iv.getWidth()));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Width : " + learn_full_iv.getWidth() + "Height : " + learn_full_iv.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                playSound(7, 8);
                break;
                    default:
                    break;     
}
```

And now the problem is every time on Loading the onCreate() , the Image first clicked will display only the solid color of the image and not the whole image, as shown below:

[image: Image View Without Width & Height]

And from the next click, whether on the same image or next image, code works fine as:[image: ImageView with desired width & Height!]

And everything else works as fine until the Activity is restarted. If we restart or resume this Activity the same thing is happening.

So, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved it & figured it out my self , Actually it is a small look over for android loading of images:

```
  @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        learn_full_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        learn_full_iv.startAnimation(anim);

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.a:
            //learn_full_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.aeroplane);
            learn_full_iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.aeroplane, learn_full_iv.getWidth(), learn_full_iv.getWidth()));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Width : " + learn_full_iv.getWidth() + "Height : " + learn_full_iv.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            playSound(1, 2);
            break;
    ...........
```

The problem in the above code is that I am just enabling the ImageView "learn_full_iv" just at the start of the run method which will have the width & height as "0" by default as the image is still not set on the ImageView

and so if we are calling :

```
 learn_full_iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.aeroplane, learn_full_iv.getWidth(), learn_full_iv.getWidth()));
```

The width & height will be zero in this case so, just a asolid color from that image will be displayed.So , I used a **method** to get width & height of the screen as Integer values & passed them to the corresponding width & height sections in the above BITMAP DECODE method.

Thats it , as now we are having the width & height as values , th bitmap will be shown now.

Simple!!!

Comment: i fell in that pit fall too. Thanks you helped me out of the pit :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Clarify :

1. why are you calling the switch cod in runnable ??
2. And where are you calling the handler to run ??

Make sure not to call the handler start method in onresume/onstart method also make sure oncreate is not called again in case of orientation change